# Printing (number, uncertainty) pair in a formal way

Tags: python, strings, formatting

I am trying to do an auxilliary function to print pairs of value-uncertainty in a formal way, given their name, value and uncertainty.

The "technical" agreement is that "uncertainty rules", meaning that the significant digits of a pair to be printed are given by the decimal size of the uncertainty value. For example: real values (123.456789, 0.012345) should be converted to a representation of (123.456, 0.012), and real values (123456.789, 123.45) should be converted to a representation of (123450, 120).

Additional rules:

- If an uncertainty is greater than 10^3 or smaller than 10^-3, then exponent notation will be used with 1 decimal digit for the *value* (ideally, the pair should share the exponent factor which would be given by the *value* exponent factor, but I don't know how to do that yet - I marked it as *to-do* in the code). For example, (6.31e+03, 0.31e+03) would be the ideal, now I am getting (6.310000e+03, 3.1000000e+02).
- Don't print decimal point if the uncertainty value is greater than 10.

Some options I try to give:

Whitespace formatting:

```
'{:{ws}{nfmt}}'.format(ws = ' ' if ws in [True, ' '] else '', nfmt = ...)
# nfmt stands for number formatting, e.g. .1f, etc. see code.
```

Representation formatting: useful for latex, unicode printing, simple/ascii or shorthand notation (I don't know how to implement exponent notation in short notation representation, that's why I refer to making a custom repr method in the code).

- Simple/ascii: `0.210+/-0.011`
- Short: `0.210(11) # uncertainty takes integer form. I don't know how to do this one`
- Short-composite: `0.210(0.011)`
- Fancy/utf-8: `0.210 ± 0.011`
- Latex: `$0.210 \pm 0.011$`

Note that the exponent factor should be printed outside: if it was (0.000210, 0.000011) (to comply with condition of u <= 10^-3), it should print `(2.10 ± 0.11)e-04` and variants or `210(11)e-06` for short notation. I don't know how to simply do neither of them either :(.

Edit: the short notation is more complicated than I thought. I added what it should look like on short+exponent notation. Also added exponent condition for small numbers.

Edit #2: I'm seeing a lot of bad style here. Technically, exponent notation should be also printed outside for all the representations. That's another reason to do a specific formal `repr` function for pairs. Now I'm realizing that this probably isn't a good post. If somebody tells me to, I'll delete the post and redo it after I've given it a better try. Only issue is I should probably be studying for finals :p

Here is the full code:

```
def _print_fres(names, vals, uncs, sigds = 2, rfmt = 'pm', ws = False):
# sigds are the significance digits
# inputs are lists of names, values and uncertainties respectively
    try:
        if all([str(u).lower() not in 'inf' for u in uncs]):
                sigs = [
                    (re.search('[1-9]', str(u)).start()-2 \
                        if re.match('0\.', str(u)) \
                    else -re.search('\.', str(float(u))).start())+sigds \
                    for u in uncs
                    ]
                # significant digits rule in uncertainty
        else:
            print('Warning: infinity in uncertainty values')
            sigs = [sigds] * len(uncs)
    except TypeError: #NaN or None
        raise TypeError('Error: odd uncertainty values')

    rfmt = rfmt.lower()
    # this can be done better/prettier I think
    if rfmt in ['fancy', 'pms']: # pms stands for pmsign
        res_str = '{{0}} = {{1:{ws}{nfmt}}} ± {{2:{ws}{nfmt}}}'
    elif rfmt in ['basic', 'pm', 'ascii']:
        res_str = '{{0}} = {{1:{ws}{nfmt}}}+/-{{2:{ws}{nfmt}}}'
    elif rfmt in ['tex', 'latex']:
        res_str = '${{0}} = {{1:{ws}{nfmt}}} \\pm {{2:{ws}{nfmt}}}$'
    elif rfmt in ['s1', 'short1']:
        res_str = '{{0}} = {{1:{ws}{nfmt}}} ± {{2:{ws}{nfmt}}}'
        # not yet supported. to do: shorthand notation
    elif rfmt in ['s2', 'short2']:
        res_str = '{{0}} = {{1:{ws}{nfmt}}}({{2:{ws}{nfmt}}})'
    else:
        raise KeyError('rfmt value is invalid')

    for i in range(len(vals)):
        try:
            print((res_str.format(
                    nfmt = '1e' if uncs[i] >= 1000 or uncs[i] <= 0.001 \
                    # 1 decimal exponent notation for big/small numbers
                        else (
                            'd' if sigs[i] <= 0 \
                            # integer if uncertainty >= 10
                            else '.{}f'.format(sigs[i])),
                    ws = ' ' if ws in [True, ' '] else ''
                    )
                 ).format(
                    names[i],
                    round(vals[i], sigs[i]),
                    round(uncs[i], sigs[i])
                    # round to allow non-decimal significances
                 )
             )

        except (TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError) as e:
            print('{} value is invalid'.format(uncs[i]))
            print(e)
            continue
    # to do: a repr method to get numbers well represented
    # instead of this whole mess
```

Comment: What does "(123.456789, 0.012345) should be a representation of (123.456, 0.012)" mean? Is either tuple a decimal with its uncertainty? If so, which one, and what is the other tuple?

Comment: @l0b0 sorry, I meant "converted to representation of"; edited. Either way, both of them are pairs of numbers, not necessarily tuples. The program takes a list of measurements a list of their uncertainties, that's why the inputs are lists instead of single elements. Also, the function is was originally intended to be private since it's a minor part of a much bigger function/algorithm. I'm working on a solution via class, however. I'll probably post it in another post since it's completely different? I don't know, I'm new to this site and haven't really taken the time to read the whole faq.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some suggestions:

- Rather than explaining parameters in comments, simply name the variables so that the comments become unnecessary. A signature of `def format_uncertain_values(names, values, uncertainties, significant_digits=2, format='pm', word_separated=False)` should do it.
- There are three distinct sections to your method, which should probably be separate methods.
- This code is a great candidate for [type hints](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html). Declare types using for example `names: typing.List[str]` and validate them using the `mypy` command line tool (be sure to look into the MyPy options, because the default configuration is very lax). This will highlight at least one implementation issue: `ws` is treated as *either* a boolean or a string, but

  - boolean arguments are a code smell ([1](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/147977/13162), [2](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/323554/13162)) and
  - making it a string (possibly defaulting it to the empty string) would remove the need for the `ws = ' ' if …` line.
- The code would be much simpler if it simply took a *single* name, value and uncertainty. Then the user

  - avoids having to wrap everything in lists to format a single variable and
  - can still trivially loop over their values to print all of them.
- Send the code through at least one linter such as `flake8` or `pycodestyle` until it passes all the tests. Then your code will be much more idiomatic, and therefore easier to read and maintain for people familiar with Python.
- Default arguments are IMO a code smell. They should only really be used if it is completely obvious what the default is, even for someone who only reads the body of the method.
- The format names are magic strings, and as such should be either constants or enums.
- The format synonyms such as `['fancy', 'pms']` feel like over-engineering. If you're the only user for now, why make your code more complicated than it needs to be?
- The method should `return` rather than `print()` the result (see above about handling only a single variable at a time) so that it can be *reused* by other code. It would be trivial to add a wrapper like `def main()` to `print()` it.

Comment: Why are boolean arguments a code smell? I see them used frequently in libraries such as scipy, pandas, etc.